# Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015_64bit) When executing step "qmake"

Tags: qt, windows-10, qt-creator

I just installed Qt, but when I try to compile a basic program I get the error:

```
Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015_64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

This is the program I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

What could be the problem with my set up?

Comment: This often means that something in the kit is broken

Comment: Have a look in Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits and see if there are warning or error signs and what the tool tip on the kit in the list says something interesting

Comment: Yes there are warning errors there under Qt Versions. Under Auto-detected,  `Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2015_64bit C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe` has a red exclamation mark.

Comment: and what does the tool tip over the item with the error icon in the list say?

Comment: Its doesn't say anything else. There's no tool tip message displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try online installer Given in [link below](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-windows-x86-online.exe). This will install "MinGW" a C++ compiler (I believe!) extra and then the error will go off.

I've also faced the same problem!!! I used QT offline installer and believe this don't have a compiler inside by default!

Since this is my first time with QT I looked resources to add compilers but didn't work for me, it is so confusing.

So, I decided to do fresh installation but at this time to use online installer. http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-windows-x86-online.exe